# ASPX auth cookie expiration time is always 30 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

I have set the the cookie expiration time to 1 month but when I look the expiration timeout of .ASPXAUTH cookie in browser it says 30 minutes ahead from now.

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "myname", DateTime.Now,
                                                        DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), true, "test");
string ticketString = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, ticketString)
                 {
                     Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                     Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                 };
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Can you let me know why the above code is behaving so, I want to change the expiration time but it is always coming 30 minutes.

Comment: where did you specify 1 month ?

Comment: do you have any reason to manually create the authentication ticket? If you do it automatically you can handle expiration time trough web.config.

Comment: V4Vendetta he does it here: "DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)" 

To Rocky Singh, have you checked slidingExpiration="false" property? 
I'm guessing you aren't specifying it to false or it is absent.
In this case, every request resets the Expiration to the default in Web.Config

Comment: I want to keep slidingExpiration to true along with overriding the expiration time too (which is 30 minutes by default)

Answer (score 4):

Do you require to set this timeout programmatically or is it ok to set it in configuration file? There is a *timeout* parameter, which indicates authentication cookie timeout: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx

Default value of this parameter is 30 minutes.

Best regards,
Dmitry

Answer (score 4):

With the advice from the other answers I got to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.85).aspx) link.

Apparently, in ASP.NET it checks the expiration in the Web.config and doesn't take the expiration from the cookie. So you need to add to the config file inside `<system.web>`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms
 name=".ASPXAUTH"
 loginUrl="Login.cshtml" //your login page
 defaultUrl="Default.cshtml" //your default page
 protection="All" //type of encryption
 timeout="43200" //a month in minutes
 path="/"
 requireSSL="false"
 slidingExpiration="true" //Every refresh the expiration time will reset
 cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" //Use cookies if the browser supports cookies
 domain=""
 enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check you web.config file, there should be FORM entry under following element system.web -> authentication .

check the timeout property there, is it set to 30 minutes?

remove this form authentication tag from there.

Comment: It is just     <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: try to add domain to forms tag (any string), I had the same problem , I had to set it to 240 minutes, I made both the entry same in web.config and in code and added domain in form tag. I also made Application Pool timeout in IIS to 240 minutes.